# Bloc Listener : access to the previous state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

There is one line of my code in my `BlocListener` that I would like to run only if a condition on the previous state is met. So is it possible to get access to the previous state in the `listener`, I know I can get access to it in the `listenWhen` parameter.

```dart
BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              switch (state.status) {
                case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:

                  context.read<GetOffersCubit>().getOffersInMyArea();
                  context.read<GetRequestsCubit>().getRequestsInMyArea();
                  context.read<GetFavoritesCubit>().getFavorites();
                  PushNotificationsManager instanceNotificationManager = PushNotificationsManager();
                  instanceNotificationManager.init(state.user.id);

                  // this line should run only if previous.status != AuthenticationStatus.authenticated
                  context.read<NavigatorBloc>().add(GoToMainFrameScreen());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the status to a list every time it changes then access the previous status from the list.

I can't test this of course because I don't have your full code but something like this should work.

```
 List statusList = [];
 BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              statusList.add(state.status); // adding to list before hitting switch/case
              switch (state.status) {
                case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:

                  context.read<GetOffersCubit>().getOffersInMyArea();
                  context.read<GetRequestsCubit>().getRequestsInMyArea();
                  context.read<GetFavoritesCubit>().getFavorites();
                  PushNotificationsManager instanceNotificationManager = PushNotificationsManager();
                  instanceNotificationManager.init(state.user.id);
                
                  final previousStatusIndex = statusList.length - 1;
                  final previousStatus = statusList[previousStatusIndex];

          // this line should run only if previous.status != AuthenticationStatus.authenticated

                  if (previousStatus != AuthenticationStatus.authenticated) {
                 
                  context.read<NavigatorBloc>().add(GoToMainFrameScreen());
                    }
```

Comment: However shouldn't I add the status to the list _after_ the switch case ? Because otherwise `statusList[previousStateIndex]` would represent the current state, don't you think ?

Comment: Well, as I said I couldn't test it, but the listener gets called every time the state changes, so I was thinking that by the time you're inside the listener method, `statusList[statusList.length]` would be the current state and `statusList[previousStatusIndex]` would be the previous. But thats easily checkable in the de-bugger and easily fixable if that's not the case.

Comment: Yeah, by putting it right after the switch case, it produced the desired behavior. Now everything works well, thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you asked for is built in.
[Bloc documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocListener-class.html)

```
BlocListener<BlocA, BlocAState>(
    listenWhen: (previousState, currentState) {
        //return true to invoke listener function
        return true;  
    },
    listener: (context, state) {
        // do stuff here based on BlocA's state
    },
    child: Container(),
)
```